# Trouble with pointers while making hashmap in C

Tags: c, pointers, hashmap

for a C introduction I need to make a hashmap. These are the structures that I made so far:

```
typedef struct HashEntry {
    char *key;
    void* data;
    struct HashEntry *next;
}HashEntry;

typedef struct HashMap {
    size_t key_space;
    hash_function* function;
    HashEntry *data;
}HashMap;
```

When I want to make a new hashlist, I use these commands:

```
HashMap *hm = calloc(1, sizeof(HashMap));
hm->data = calloc(key_space, sizeof(HashEntry));
```

So far I guess this is a good design, but I have some problems when I want to add a value that has a key that already exists in my map. (In that case, I want the old value to be free'ed, and the new value to be allocated.

I thought that the following code shoud do the trick:

```
void* old = current->data;
free(old);
current->data=malloc(length);
current->data = newData;     // newdata is a void* type
```

However my code just stops running, I guess I made a mistake with the pointers but after trying to find it for quite a while I'm a bit depressed.

Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

Some clarification after the questions:
the code stops executing after:

```
free(old);
```

If I uncomment this it works, but why wouldn't I be able to free the data?

Length is de size of the void* string that I want to save.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stops running"? Is it a segmentation fault? If an error is displayed, it would be useful.

Comment: Can you tell us where your code stops ? It is probably a segfault but adding traces would help spot the bug.

Comment: It would be also useful to know where "length" and "newData" come from.

Comment: if you ever find yourself doing `p = malloc(...); p = <something else>;` Stop. This isn't Java or C#. This is exactly what you're doing with `current->data` in your sample.

Comment: First, settle on your design; does adding something to the hashmap mean that the hashmap manages (owns) that resource? If so, you will need to use a memcpy instead of your `current-data = newData` for the data when adding. If not, remove both free and malloc from your add-related-code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely need to replace

```
current->data = newData;
```

with something like

```
memcpy(current->data, newData, length);
```

I assume `newData` is a pointer to your new data. And `current->data` is the pointer to the memory you first free and then allocate again.

In order to be able to use `memcpy()` you must add `#include <string.h>` at the top of your file.

Your original code may seem to work when you uncomment the `free(old)` since you then just enter the original `newData` *pointers* into your hashmap. If you try to `free()` them later bad things happen. I assume you want to enter the *data* contained in `newData` into the hasmap, not just the *pointer* to the data.

Note that the compiler will be of little help here. C is not a *managed* language, which means you need to maintain the lifetime of all your chunks of memories and semantics of all your pointers yourself. Some pointers point to malloc'd memory, some point to static data, it is really up to you and your program to maintain consistency.